# Typeahead implementation in angular 2

Tags: jhipster, typeahead

I have implemented a search operation in JHipster - it's working. Now I am try to implement typeahead concept but it does not show the suggestion box.

Can you guide me how to do this in JHipster.

Comment: Your question lacks many details like JHipster version. Is it really Angular 2 or Angular 6? Do you want to achieve this using ng-bootstrap as provided by JHipster or another UI library? Please edit your question.

Comment: As Gael mentioned, you can use ng-bootstrap that's provided in the generated Angular project, see their docs https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples